# Query failed yd_prom_stock lastcheck

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, query

I was doing a normal updates , never happen with it, and now i get this error with all the products with the update:

Query failed (Got error -1 from storage engine):

```
            UPDATE
                prom_stock
            SET
                `lastcheck` = NOW()
            WHERE
                dbase_code = 'XXXXXX'
            LIMIT 1
```

How could fail a query just for make an update to field `lastcheck = now()` ????

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE
                yd_prom_stock
            SET
                `lastcheck` = NOW()
            WHERE
                dbase_code = 'XXXXXX'
```

`LIMIT` can be used with `UPDATE` but with the `row count` only

check this [link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42415) for more information

Comment: Could you explain or show me more about this?

Comment: UPDATE statement with LIMIT clause is considered unsafe since the order of the rows affected is not defined